# eSignaure RestAPI V2 documentation direct links to v2 redirects to v2.1 documentation

Tags: docusignapi

In my code I attempt to link to relevant portions of the api documentation.  For v2 calls, these now redirect to the v2.1 documentation

For example, I navigate to the Version 2 Bulk Envelope get function.  The url displays - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/bulkenvelopes/bulkenvelopes/get.

When clicking on this same link my documenation, I am redirected to the V2.1 version at https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/bulkenvelopes/bulkenvelopes/get.

This appears to be controlled by the Version drop down on the documentation page. If the last RestAPI documentation viewed was a v2 call, the link works fine.

Is there a way to ensure my link takes the user to the correct page?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Jim for your feedback. This is something we would have to review with the team and decide how we want to proceed. I'll update this page if there's a workaround that I find or some other way for you to go directly to v2 docs.